# How do I add new data JSON data in an external file using AngularJS services

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and am having issues figuring out how to update a `$scope` element I created from a JSON external data file.

Basically I have a service that contains the function which grabs the JSON:

```
MyApp.factory("wwprService", function($http){
var _wwpr = [];

var _getwwpr = function(){
    $http.get("/js/data/wwpr.json")
        .then(function(results){
            //Success
            angular.copy(results.data, _wwpr); 
            //alert(results);
        }, function(results){
            //Error
        })
}

var _addNewwwpr = function(val1,val2,val3,val4){
    _wwpr.splice(0,0, val1, val2, val3, val4);
    $http.get("/js/data/wwpr.json") // here i want to add new datas 
}

return{
    wwpr: _wwpr,
    getwwpr: _getwwpr,
    addNewwwpr: _addNewwwpr
};
```

});

I then have a Controller that contains a function that gets the JSON data on a button click and puts it in `$scope.wwp` and a second function that I would like to use to update `$scope.wwp` in that JSON data file:

```
MyApp.controller("wwprCtrl", function ($scope, wwprService){

// Executes when the controller is created
$scope.wwpr = wwprService.wwpr;

wwprService.getwwpr();

$scope.addNewwwpr = function(wwpProjectName,wwpactivityType,wwpplanDate,wwpefforts){
//alert(wwpProjectName);
    var getProjectName = {projectName: wwpProjectName};
    var getactivityType = {activityType: wwpactivityType};
    var getplanDate = {planDate: wwpplanDate};
    var getefforts = {efforts: wwpefforts};
    wwprService.addNewwwpr(getProjectName,getactivityType,getplanDate,getefforts);
     $scope.wwpr.push({projectName: wwpProjectName});
}
```

});

#### JSON data file:

```
[
{
    "projectName": "PMD",
    "activityType": "Coding",
    "planDate": "12/12/14",
    "efforts": "8"
},
{
    "projectName": "PMD",
    "activityType": "Coding",
    "planDate": "12/12/14",
    "efforts": "8"
} //here i want add new json data
```

]

Currently, I successfully get the JSON data from external file and am able to use it to populate aspects of my view, but I am stuck on how to proceed with updating `$scope.wwp` so that:

- It actually updates
- The update is reflected in my view

I have tried `$scope.wwp.push`, `$scope.wwp.posts.push`. These have either flat out not worked or given errors. I'm sure it might be a simple answer, but I feel I may be inexperienced with AngularJS and JSON to pick up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tell AngularJS that something has changed in the asynchronous part of your code:

```
var _getwwpr = function(){
    $http.get("/js/data/wwpr.json")
        .then(function(results){

            //Success
            angular.copy(results.data, _wwpr); 
            //alert(results);
        }, function(results){

        //Error
        })
}
```

should become

```
var _getwwpr = function(){
    return $http.get("/js/data/wwpr.json")
        .then(function(results){
            //Success
            angular.copy(results.data, _wwpr); 
            //alert(results);
        }, function(results){
        //Error
        })
}
```

This way your data model will return a promise that can then be used in the view to trigger a "refresh".

```
//Controller
wwprService.getwwpr().then($scope.apply);
```

### Further Explanation

AngularJS does "dirty checking" on `$scope` objects and if they have changed it propagates those changes to and DOM bindings. The problem you have currently is that nothing in your application is telling AngularJS to re-run its dirty checking.

Re-running dirty checking is (for the most part) taken care for you by AngularJS itself on common DOM events such as click, etc. However, since you are returning data in your service that you need placed into the DOM you can use `$scope.apply()` to trigger this manually so to speak.